# Mass Merge in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, merge

currently we have a TFS Server that has a few files with many branches, however some of them are basically just links as they copy and overwrite from the main without any independent action.  I haven't found a way to do a "Mass Merge" that is just copy the main file content into all the branched files.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

EDIT: This is Team Foundation Server 2010 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way, certainly not from the Team Explorer GUI. You could probably script it using the command line "tf merge"